# In Elm what is the correct way to implement my own toString

Tags: elm

In Elm what is the correct way to take my Model and implement a toString function?

The type I am looking for would be `toString : Model -> String`, I am able to make a similar function with the type of `toStr : Model -> String` but I would think I would want the function to be called `toString`.

Example program (the Coin Changer kata):

```
module CoinChanger where

import Html exposing (..)
import StartApp.Simple as StartApp
import Signal exposing (Address)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on, targetValue)
import String


---- MAIN ----


main =
  StartApp.start 
  {
       model = emptyModel
      ,update = update
      ,view = view
  }


---- Model ----


type alias Model =
    {
        change : List Int
    }


emptyModel : Model
emptyModel =
    {
        change = []
    }


---- VIEW ----


toStr : Model -> String
toStr model =
  model.change
  |> List.map (\coin -> (toString coin) ++ "¢")
  |> String.join ", " 


view : Address String -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  div []
  [
      input
      [
          placeholder "amount to make change for"
      ,   on "input" targetValue (Signal.message address)
      ,   autofocus True
      -- style  
      ]
      []
  ,   div []
      [
          text (toStr model)
      ]
  ]


---- UPDATE ----


changeFor : Int -> List Int
changeFor amount =
  [ 25, 10, 5, 1 ]
  |> List.foldl
    (\coin (change, amount)
      -> ( change ++ List.repeat (amount // coin) coin
         , amount % coin)
    )
    ([], amount)
  |> fst



update : String -> Model -> Model
update change model =
  { model | change =
      case String.toInt change of
        Ok amount 
            -> changeFor amount

        Err msg
            -> []
  }
```

I would think the correct way to do this would be to call the function `toString`, but that gives me the following error from the compiler:

> Detected errors in 1 module.
>   -- TYPE MISMATCH ----------------------------------------------- CoinChanger.elm
>
> The type annotation for `toString` does not match its definition.
>
> 42│ toString : Model -> String
>                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ The type annotation is saying:
>
> ```
> { change : List Int } -> String
> ```
>
> But I am inferring that the definition has this type:
>
> ```
> { change : List { change : List Int } } -> String
> ```

Renaming the function to `toStr` (or something not called `toString`) fixes the issue but seems wrong.  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, calling your function `toString`, you are overriding the `toString` function of the `Basics` module, which you are using at line 45.

To avoid this, you'll need to import the `Basics` module and use `Basics.toString` instead of simply `toString` to eliminare the ambiguity

Comment: I changed line 45 to `|> List.map (\coin -> (Basics.toString coin) ++ "¢")` and everything worked just like you said.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is well out of date for anyone writing Elm 0.19+. The current solution is to write your own `toString` function for the type you want converted. There is a `Debug.toString` for use during development but its use in your code will prevent building for production.